# Select all element that start with a specific numbers

Tags: java

Here is my code:

```
if(Rs.getInt("Number") == 100){
 //Do something
}
```

`Rs` is a `PreparedStatement`.

Instead of defining the exact number, I want to look for numbers
    which start with 1. Maybe there are '110' or '120' ... what should i write in the loop 
    instead of the operator `==` ?

Comment: `Rs.getString("Number").startsWith("1")` :O

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Otherwise i would accept your first suggestion if you could modify your answer,since i want to select as well the values that start with 2 separately,then all values start with 3 and so on ..

Comment: Mate, look over the [String.startsWith](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#startsWith(java.lang.String)) method and use it with what prefixes you wish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This guy here seems to have the right idea.

[Retrieving the first digit of a number](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2967898)

```
if ("1".equals(Integer.parseInt(Rs.getInt(number).substring(0, 1)))){
//do stuff
}
```

Comment: OK, I'll flag as a duplicate.

Comment: Did that work for you?

Comment: i think it s not the same request ! As i wanted to select all the records which  started with 1. For example if i have 110 ,199,13123,1424. It should retrieve them all as they start with 1.Thanks

Comment: @user5953665 no, I'm afraid it's a duplicate. Retrieving the first digit of the number allows you to branch off if it's a 1. You can't ask for code personally tailored to your own situation.