# Get a specific digit of a number from an int in Java

Tags: java, arrays, int

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Return first digit of an integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2051817/return-first-digit-of-an-integer)

In my java program, I store a number in an array.

```
p1Wins[0] = 123;
```

How would I check the first digit of `p1Wins[0]`? Or the second or third? I just need to be able to find the value of any specific digit.

Thanks!

Comment: Convert it to a string and use `charAt`? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Out of curiosity: what's the use case of this? Why do you need to get that digit? There might be better ways to achieve your ultimate goal, so you might want to elaborate a bit on that.

Answer (score 25):

[Modular arithmetic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic) can be used to accomplish what you want. For example, if you divide `123` by `10`, and take the remainder, you'd get the first digit `3`. If you do integer division of `123` by `100` and then divide the result by `10`, you'd get the second digit `2`. More generally, the `n`-th digit of a number can be obtained by the formula `(number / base^(n-1)) % base`:

```
public int getNthDigit(int number, int base, int n) {    
  return (int) ((number / Math.pow(base, n - 1)) % base);
}

System.out.println(getNthDigit(123, 10, 1));  // 3
System.out.println(getNthDigit(123, 10, 2));  // 2
System.out.println(getNthDigit(123, 10, 3));  // 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Tried

```
String.valueOf(Math.abs((long)x)).charAt(0)
```

?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to do some math magic to get the nth digit of an arbitrary number, basically using division and modulo 10 if you want it to be a number. Otherwise string ops will work.

```
int nth ( int number, int index ) {
    return ((int)number / java.lang.Math.pow(10, index)) % 10;
}

char nth ( int number, int index ) {
    return String.valueOf(java.lang.Math.abs(number)).charAt(index);
}
```

Mind you the modulo method will take form the right side and the string will take from the left;

Comment: I don't think you want to use exclusive-or (`^`) there.

Comment: @GregHewgill - haha yeah, sorry I prototyped the function in psudeo code and then suddenly couldn't remember the `Math.pow` function so I had to go look it up.

Answer (score 0):

```
Integer(plWins[0]).toString().charAt(0)
```

You're turning your number into a string and then performing a charAt. 0 can be replaced with any other character, as well.  It's not too elegant, but I believe Java does not provide any more straightforward a method.  You may also choose to cast it to an int if char is not your preferred type.