# Find target digit of an integer

Tags: java, digit, radix-sort

What methods can I employ to return a specific digit of an integer?

```
//val = number to find target digit on
//dig = the digit to return from right-side
private int digit(int val, int dig) {
    String num = "" + val;
    return Character.getNumericValue(num.charAt(num.length-dig));
}
```

For example, if `val` were "48602" and I wanted to grab the 2nd digits (tenths), it would return "0".

Here's an ugly way to do it, but is there a way without using strings at all? Perhaps with modulo? What if I wanted to find the 7th digit (millionths), this method wouldn't even work (the number would have to be parsed as "0048602").

Potential use would be for a Radix sort (putting numbers into "buckets" based on significant digits). I'm finding using this method is relatively taxing.

Comment: <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9253716/get-a-specific-digit-of-a-number-from-an-int-in-java>   looks limiler

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an idea

```
private int digit(int val,int dig){
    int div = 1;
    for(int i=0;i<dig;i++)
        div*=10; //make 10^dig
    val/=div; //remove the smaller digits
    return val%10; //return only one digit
}
```

Not tested

**EDIT** better way:

```
private int digit(int val,int dig){
    int div = (int)Math.pow(10,dig);
    val/=div; //remove the smaller digits
    return val%10; //return only one digit
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with the following code:

```
public int getDigit(int n, int i) {    
    return (n / ((int) Math.pow(10, i))) % 10;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use

```
    return ((val%(Math.pow(10, dig))) - (val%(Math.pow(10, dig-1))))/(Math.pow(10, dig-1));
```

Where

```
(val%(Math.pow(10, dig)))
```

takes off the front digits

```
- (val%(Math.pow(10, dig-1)))
```

subtracts the trailing digits,
and

```
/(Math.pow(10, dig-1)
```

takes off the remaining zeros