# How to print an integer with commas every 'd' digits, from right to left

Tags: java, loops, for-loop

I had to write a program that will receive an int 'n' and another one 'd' - and will print the number n with commas every d digits from right to left. 
If 'n' or 'd' are negative - the program will print 'n' as is.
I although had to make sure that there is no commas before or after the number and I'm not allowed to use String or Arrays.

for example: n = 12345678

d=1: 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8

d=3: 12,345,678

I've written the following code:

```
public static void printWithComma(int n, int d) {
    if (n < 0 || d <= 0) {
        System.out.println(n);
    } else {
        int reversedN = reverseNum(n), copyOfrereversedN = reversedN, counter = numberLength(n);
        while (reversedN > 0) {
            System.out.print(reversedN % 10);
            reversedN /= 10;
            counter--;
            if (counter % d == 0 && reversedN != 0) {
                System.out.print(",");
            }
        }
        /*
         * In a case which the received number will end with zeros, the reverse method
         * will return the number without them. In that case the length of the reversed
         * number and the length of the original number will be different - so this
         * while loop will end the zero'z at the right place with the commas at the
         * right place
         */
        while (numberLength(copyOfrereversedN) != numberLength(n)) {
            if (counter % d == 0) {
                System.out.print(",");
            }
            System.out.print(0);
            counter--;
            copyOfrereversedN *= 10;
        }
    }
}
```

that uses a reversNum function:

```
// The method receives a number n and return his reversed number(if the number
// ends with zero's - the method will return the number without them)
public static int reverseNum(int n) {
    if (n < 9) {
        return n;
    }
    int reversedNum = 0;
    while (n > 0) {
        reversedNum += (n % 10);
        reversedNum *= 10;
        n /= 10;
    }
    return (reversedNum / 10);
}
```

and numberLength method:

```
// The method receives a number and return his length ( 0 is considered as "0"
// length)
public static int numberLength(int n) {
    int counter = 0;
    while (n > 0) {
        n /= 10;
        counter++;
    }
    return counter;
}
```

I've been told that the code doesn't work for every case, and i am unable to think about such case (the person who told me that won't tell me).

Thank you for reading!

Comment: What is `numberLength()`?

Comment: Seems to print nothing if `n = 0`

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems overly complicated.

If you've learned about recursion, you can do it like this:

```
public static void printWithComma(int n, int d) {
    printInternal(n, d, 1);
    System.out.println();
}
private static void printInternal(int n, int d, int i) {
    if (n > 9) {
        printInternal(n / 10, d, i + 1);
        if (i % d == 0)
            System.out.print(',');
    }
    System.out.print(n % 10);
}
```

Without recursion:

```
public static void printWithComma(int n, int d) {
    int rev = 0, i = d - 1;
    for (int num = n; num > 0 ; num /= 10, i++)
        rev = rev * 10 + num % 10;
    for (; i > d; rev /= 10, i--) {
        System.out.print(rev % 10);
        if (i % d == 0)
            System.out.print(',');
    }
    System.out.println(rev);
}
```

Comment: That code is complicated for sure,but i'm not allowed to use neither Strings, Arrays or recursion.

Answer (score 1):

You solved looping through the digits by reversing the number, so a simple division by ten can be done to receive all digits in order.

The comma position is calculated from the right.

```
public static void printWithComma(int n, int d) {
    if (n < 0) {
        System.out.print('-');
        n = -n;
    }
    if (n == 0) {
        System.out.print('0');
        return;
    }
    int length = numberLength(n);
    int reversed = reverseNum(n);

    for (int i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
        int nextDigit = reversed % 10;
        System.out.print(nextDigit);
        reversed /= 10;

        int fromRight = length - 1 - i;
        if (fromRight != 0 && fromRight % d == 0) {
            System.out.print(',');
        }
    }
}
```

This is basically the same code as yours. However I store the results of the help functions into variables.

A zero is a special case, an exception of the rule that leading zeros are dropped.

Every d<sup>th</sup> digit (from right) needs to print comma, but not entirely at the right. And not in front. Realized by printing the digit first and then possibly the comma.

The problems I see with your code are the two while loops, twice printing the comma, maybe? And the println with a newline when <= 0.

Test your code, for instance as:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (int n : new int[] {0, 1, 8, 9, 10, 234,
                   1_234, 12_345, 123_456, 123_456_789, 1_234_567_890}) {
        System.out.printf("%d : ", n);
        printWithComma(n, 3);
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Comment: Since `reverseNum()` from the question is flawed, and you're using it, your code is flawed. `printWithComma(999999999, 3)` prints `935,600,141`

Comment: @Andreas this is a homework task or such, I did refrain rewriting it for the OP, despite seeing that hacky code.

Comment: The OP mentioned that already someone told him about there being a flaw. Simplifying printWithComma should help.

Comment: Simplifying? You mean like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59522597/5221149)? ;-)

Comment: @Andreas yes that is the best solution, though I did want to follow the OP's work a bit..

Answer (score 0):

Are you allowed to use the whole Java API?

What about something as simple as using `DecimalFormat`

```
double in = 12345678;
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat( ",##" );
System.out.println(df.format(in));
```

> 12,34,56,78

---

Using...

- `,#` = 1 per group
- `,##` = 2 per group
- `,###` = 3 per group
  etc...

Comment: I guess, it isn't.

Comment: Question says *"I'm not allowed to use String or Arrays"*. `",##"` is a string (literal), and the return value of `format()` is a string too. Beside, the input is *"an int 'n' and another one 'd'"*, so how would you get this code from that input, *at runtime*?

Answer (score 0):

It took me a bunch of minutes. The following code snippet does the job well (**explanation below**):

```
public static void printWithComma(int n, int d) {             // n=number, d=commaIndex

    final int length = (int) (Math.log10(n) + 1);                   // number of digits;

    for (int i = 1; i < Math.pow(10, length); i*=10) {        // loop by digits
        double current = Math.log10(i);                       // current loop
        double remains = length - current - 1;                // loops remaining
        int digit = (int) ((n / Math.pow(10, remains)) % 10); // nth digit

        System.out.print(digit);                              // print it

        if (remains % d == 0 && remains > 0) {                // add comma if qualified
            System.out.print(",");
        }
    }
}
```

- Using `(Math.log10(n) + 1)` I find a number of digits in the integer (`8` for `12345678`).
- The `for-loop` assures the exponents of `n` series (1, 10, 100, 1000...) needed for further calculations. Using logarithm of base 10 I get the current index of the loop.
- To get n<sup>th</sup> digit is a bit tricky and this formula is based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9253758/3764965). Then it is printed out.
- Finally, it remains to find a qualified position for the comma (`,`). If modulo of the current loop index is equal zero, the d<sup>th</sup> index is reached and the comma can be printed out. Finally the condition `remains > 0` assures there will be no comma left at the end of the printed result.

Output:

> For **4**: 1234,5678
>
> For **3**: 12,345,678
>
> For **2**: 12,34,56,78
>
> For **1**: 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8

Comment: `printWithComma(1000000000, 1)` causes infinite loop.