# Know the number in a determinate position from a String - Java

Tags: java, android, string, int

I'm getting a number from an addition of Int and then put it as String. I need to know what is the first, second etc. number of the addition. For example the number is 7654, how to know that "7" is the first number? And "6" the second? etc.

```
          String result += "\nThe result of addition"
          + String.valueOf(add_1) + "+" + String.valueOf(add_2) 
          "+ is" + String.valueOf(int_result);
```

I want to know the number of a determinate position of the String that contain the result. 
The string is String.valueOf(int_result), I can use directly int_result too.
Thanks!

Comment: couldn't you first store int_result in a variable as a string and parse the first character of the string?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Return first digit of an integer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2051817/return-first-digit-of-an-integer)

Comment: I need every digits, not only the first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just walk each character in the resulting string:

```
String result = String.valueOf(int_result);
for (int i=0; i< result.length(); i++) {
    char c = result.charAt(i);
    System.out.println("Digit " + i + " = " + c);
    // And if you need this as an integer
    int digit = Integer.parseInt(""+c); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In Java to get the character at a particular position in a string just use this

```
String number ="7564";
char c = number.charAt(0);
```

The above code will asign '5' to char variable c. You can further parse it to integer by doing this

```
int i = Integer.parseInt(c);
```

Comment: EKJ was faster..thanks for the aswer, it's correct too:)