# How to print the digits of a two digit number separately in Java?

Tags: java

print two digit integer as two different number

`int x=32;`

*how to split it as two individuals like:*

```
int x=3;
int y=2;
```

Comment: Basic math operations like division and modulo will help.

Comment: It is not needed to ask us to answer. That is what we are here for!

Comment: X=num/10; y=num %10;

Answer (score 0):

You could convert the int to a String and then take the first and second characters. eg.

```
final int x = 32;
System.out.println("First digit:" + String.valueOf(x).charAt(0));
System.out.println("Second digit:" + String.valueOf(x).charAt(1));
```

For a general solution to integers of any length see the answers here: [Return first digit of an integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2051817/return-first-digit-of-an-integer)

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways you can do that. You could use basic math operations to do it as well. However here is another way you could go about solving this problem. That is by using the built in stack in java. Here's the code. Just try running it.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Stack;

public class test_driver{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Stack<Integer> myStack = new Stack<Integer>();
        int n, r;
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a number: ");
        n = in.nextInt();
        while(n != 0){
            r = n % 10;
            n = n / 10;
            myStack.push(r);
        }
        while(!myStack.isEmpty()){
            System.out.println(myStack.pop());
        }
    }
}
```

Hope it helped.